# Veeam Backup failing. Cannot create a shadow copy of the volumes containing writers data

Tags: windows-server-2003, backup, vmware-esxi, vss, veeam

We have a Windows Server 2003 R2 SP2 VMWare VM that is failing Veeam backups with the following error:

Failed to prepare guest for hot backup. Error: VSSControl: 1 Backup job failed. Cannot create a shadow copy of the volumes containing writer's data. Cannot serialize BackupComponents document. Cannot save the Backup Components Document. Path: [C:\WINDOWS\VeeamVssSupport\metadata\VSS\BackupComponents.xml]. Cannot create a XML tree based on the Backup Components Document. Cannot parse XML document. Document: [

The server has been rebooted but still returns the same error.

The server is on a domain and the user account has access to the server. Disk space is also not an issue with 12.9Gb free. VMWare Tools is at v10.0.0 build-3000743.

vssadmin list writers shows all writers in a stable state before running the Veeam backup. After the backup is attempted, the following show a state of Failed - Registry Writer, WMI Writer and Event Log Writer. Restarting the "Volume Shadow Copy" and "Windows Management Instrumentation" services returns the writers back to stable but the backup still fails.

I've checked the VeeamGuestHelper.log file which has the following errors:

```
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868                                      Creating an offline version of writers metadata.
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868                                              [Event Log Writer] processing in progress. Instance ID: [{77268f2a-2cb2-4c48-a233-c0660846fca0}]. Class ID: [{eee8c692-67ed-4250-8d86-390603070d00}]
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868                                              [Event Log Writer] processing in progress. Instance ID: [{77268f2a-2cb2-4c48-a233-c0660846fca0}]. Class ID: [{eee8c692-67ed-4250-8d86-390603070d00}]. Failed.
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868  ERR                                         Cannot store writer's metadata. Writer class ID: [{eee8c692-67ed-4250-8d86-390603070d00}]. Writer instance ID: [{77268f2a-2cb2-4c48-a233-c0660846fca0}]. Writer display name: [Event Log Writer].
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868  ERR                                         Cannot parse XML document. Document: [<WRITER_METADATA xmlns="x-schema:#VssWriterMetadataInfo" version="1.1"><IDENTIFICATION writerId="eee8c692-67ed-4250-8d86-390603070d00" instanceId="77268f2a-2cb2-4c48-a233-c0660846fca0" friendlyName="Event Log Writer" usage="SYSTEM_SERVICE" dataSource="OTHER"/><RESTORE_METHOD method="REPLACE_AT_REBOOT" writerRestore="never" rebootRequired="yes"/><BACKUP_LOCATIONS><FILE_GROUP componentName="Event Logs" caption="Event Logs" restoreMetadata="no" notifyOnBackupComplete="no" selectable="yes" selectableForRestore="no" componentFlags="0"><FILE_LIST path="%SystemRoot%\system32\config" filespec="AppEvent.Evt" alternatePath="%SystemRoot%\Repair\Backup\ServiceState\EventLogs" filespecBackupType="3855"/><FILE_LIST path="C:\WINDOWS\system32\config" filespec="kaspersk.evt" alternatePath="%SystemRoot%\Repair\Backup\ServiceState\EventLogs" filespecBackupType="3855"/><FILE_LIST path="%SystemRoot%\System32\config" filespec="SecEvent.Evt" alternatePath="%SystemRoot%\Repair\Backup\ServiceState\EventLogs" filespecBackupType="3855"/><FILE_LIST path="%SystemRoot%\system32\config" filespec="SysEvent.Evt" alternatePath="%SystemRoot%\Repair\Backup\ServiceState\EventLogs" filespecBackupType="3855"/></FILE_GROUP><EXCLUDE_FILES path="%SystemRoot%\system32\config" filespec="*.evt" recursive="no"/></BACKUP_LOCATIONS></WRITER_METADATA>].
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868  ERR                                         COM error: Error opening input file: 'x-schema:#VssWriterMetadataInfo'.
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868  ERR                                         The system cannot locate the resource specified.
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868  ERR                                          Code: 0x1
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868                                              [VeeamFreezeWriter] processing in progress. Instance ID: [{026c5131-ac04-4217-9817-9affaa334635}]. Class ID: [{18ec56c4-e042-497d-a3d4-eea24284fa03}]
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868                                              [VeeamFreezeWriter] processing in progress. Instance ID: [{026c5131-ac04-4217-9817-9affaa334635}]. Class ID: [{18ec56c4-e042-497d-a3d4-eea24284fa03}]. Failed.
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868  ERR                                         Cannot store writer's metadata. Writer class ID: [{18ec56c4-e042-497d-a3d4-eea24284fa03}]. Writer instance ID: [{026c5131-ac04-4217-9817-9affaa334635}]. Writer display name: [VeeamFreezeWriter].
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868  ERR                                         Cannot parse XML document. Document: [<WRITER_METADATA xmlns="x-schema:#VssWriterMetadataInfo" version="1.1"><IDENTIFICATION writerId="18ec56c4-e042-497d-a3d4-eea24284fa03" instanceId="026c5131-ac04-4217-9817-9affaa334635" friendlyName="VeeamFreezeWriter" usage="USER_DATA" dataSource="OTHER"/><BACKUP_LOCATIONS><FILE_GROUP componentName="VeeamFreezeWriter" caption="VeeamFreezeWriter" restoreMetadata="no" notifyOnBackupComplete="no" selectable="yes" selectableForRestore="yes" componentFlags="0"/></BACKUP_LOCATIONS></WRITER_METADATA>].
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868  ERR                                         COM error: Error opening input file: 'x-schema:#VssWriterMetadataInfo'.
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868  ERR                                         The system cannot locate the resource specified.
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868  ERR                                          Code: 0x1
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868                                              [COM+ REGDB Writer] processing in progress. Instance ID: [{aa69744d-b494-4df9-9cdd-fb494395ea06}]. Class ID: [{542da469-d3e1-473c-9f4f-7847f01fc64f}]
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868                                              [COM+ REGDB Writer] processing in progress. Instance ID: [{aa69744d-b494-4df9-9cdd-fb494395ea06}]. Class ID: [{542da469-d3e1-473c-9f4f-7847f01fc64f}]. Failed.
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868  ERR                                         Cannot store writer's metadata. Writer class ID: [{542da469-d3e1-473c-9f4f-7847f01fc64f}]. Writer instance ID: [{aa69744d-b494-4df9-9cdd-fb494395ea06}]. Writer display name: [COM+ REGDB Writer].
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868  ERR                                         Cannot parse XML document. Document: [<WRITER_METADATA xmlns="x-schema:#VssWriterMetadataInfo" version="1.1"><IDENTIFICATION writerId="542da469-d3e1-473c-9f4f-7847f01fc64f" instanceId="aa69744d-b494-4df9-9cdd-fb494395ea06" friendlyName="COM+ REGDB Writer" usage="BOOTABLE_SYSTEM_STATE" dataSource="OTHER"/><RESTORE_METHOD method="CUSTOM" writerRestore="never" rebootRequired="no"/><BACKUP_LOCATIONS><EXCLUDE_FILES path="%SystemRoot%\Registration" filespec="*" recursive="yes"/><FILE_GROUP componentName="COM+ REGDB" caption="COM+ REGDB" restoreMetadata="no" notifyOnBackupComplete="no" selectable="yes" selectableForRestore="no" componentFlags="0"><FILE_LIST path="%SystemRoot%\Repair\Backup\BootableSystemState\ComRegistrationDatabase" filespec="*" recursive="yes" filespecBackupType="3855"/></FILE_GROUP></BACKUP_LOCATIONS></WRITER_METADATA>].
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868  ERR                                         COM error: Error opening input file: 'x-schema:#VssWriterMetadataInfo'.
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868  ERR                                         The system cannot locate the resource specified.
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868  ERR                                          Code: 0x1
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868                                              [MSDEWriter] processing in progress. Instance ID: [{2fb80071-eb0a-4650-9fd8-3e7790010a65}]. Class ID: [{f8544ac1-0611-4fa5-b04b-f7ee00b03277}]
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868                                              [MSDEWriter] processing in progress. Instance ID: [{2fb80071-eb0a-4650-9fd8-3e7790010a65}]. Class ID: [{f8544ac1-0611-4fa5-b04b-f7ee00b03277}]. Failed.
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868  ERR                                         Cannot store writer's metadata. Writer class ID: [{f8544ac1-0611-4fa5-b04b-f7ee00b03277}]. Writer instance ID: [{2fb80071-eb0a-4650-9fd8-3e7790010a65}]. Writer display name: [MSDEWriter].
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868  ERR                                         Cannot parse XML document. Document: [<WRITER_METADATA xmlns="x-schema:#VssWriterMetadataInfo" version="1.1"><IDENTIFICATION writerId="f8544ac1-0611-4fa5-b04b-f7ee00b03277" instanceId="2fb80071-eb0a-4650-9fd8-3e7790010a65" friendlyName="MSDEWriter" usage="SYSTEM_SERVICE" dataSource="TRANSACTION_DB"/><RESTORE_METHOD method="RESTORE_IF_CAN_BE_REPLACED" writerRestore="always" rebootRequired="no"/></WRITER_METADATA>].
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868  ERR                                         COM error: Error opening input file: 'x-schema:#VssWriterMetadataInfo'.
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868  ERR                                         The system cannot locate the resource specified.
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868  ERR                                          Code: 0x1
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868                                              [WMI Writer] processing in progress. Instance ID: [{702ef282-903f-46ed-aae5-7285f8a3eb52}]. Class ID: [{a6ad56c2-b509-4e6c-bb19-49d8f43532f0}]
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868                                              [WMI Writer] processing in progress. Instance ID: [{702ef282-903f-46ed-aae5-7285f8a3eb52}]. Class ID: [{a6ad56c2-b509-4e6c-bb19-49d8f43532f0}]. Failed.
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868  ERR                                         Cannot store writer's metadata. Writer class ID: [{a6ad56c2-b509-4e6c-bb19-49d8f43532f0}]. Writer instance ID: [{702ef282-903f-46ed-aae5-7285f8a3eb52}]. Writer display name: [WMI Writer].
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868  ERR                                         Cannot parse XML document. Document: [<WRITER_METADATA xmlns="x-schema:#VssWriterMetadataInfo" version="1.1"><IDENTIFICATION writerId="a6ad56c2-b509-4e6c-bb19-49d8f43532f0" instanceId="702ef282-903f-46ed-aae5-7285f8a3eb52" friendlyName="WMI Writer" usage="SYSTEM_SERVICE" dataSource="OTHER"/><BACKUP_LOCATIONS><FILE_GROUP componentName="WMI" caption="Windows Managment Instrumentation" restoreMetadata="no" notifyOnBackupComplete="no" selectable="no" selectableForRestore="no" componentFlags="0"><FILE_LIST path="C:\WINDOWS\system32\WBEM\Repository" filespec="*.*" recursive="yes" filespecBackupType="3855"/></FILE_GROUP></BACKUP_LOCATIONS><RESTORE_METHOD method="REPLACE_AT_REBOOT" writerRestore="never" rebootRequired="yes"/></WRITER_METADATA>].
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868  ERR                                         COM error: Error opening input file: 'x-schema:#VssWriterMetadataInfo'.
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868  ERR                                         The system cannot locate the resource specified.
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868  ERR                                          Code: 0x1
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868                                              [Registry Writer] processing in progress. Instance ID: [{acd8c3f4-9cbe-4abe-a0d9-449b10fa6f6d}]. Class ID: [{afbab4a2-367d-4d15-a586-71dbb18f8485}]
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868                                              [Registry Writer] processing in progress. Instance ID: [{acd8c3f4-9cbe-4abe-a0d9-449b10fa6f6d}]. Class ID: [{afbab4a2-367d-4d15-a586-71dbb18f8485}]. Failed.
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868  ERR                                         Cannot store writer's metadata. Writer class ID: [{afbab4a2-367d-4d15-a586-71dbb18f8485}]. Writer instance ID: [{acd8c3f4-9cbe-4abe-a0d9-449b10fa6f6d}]. Writer display name: [Registry Writer].
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868  ERR                                         Cannot parse XML document. Document: [<WRITER_METADATA xmlns="x-schema:#VssWriterMetadataInfo" version="1.1"><IDENTIFICATION writerId="afbab4a2-367d-4d15-a586-71dbb18f8485" instanceId="acd8c3f4-9cbe-4abe-a0d9-449b10fa6f6d" friendlyName="Registry Writer" usage="BOOTABLE_SYSTEM_STATE" dataSource="OTHER"/><RESTORE_METHOD method="CUSTOM" writerRestore="never" rebootRequired="yes"/><BACKUP_LOCATIONS><FILE_GROUP componentName="Registry" caption="Registry" restoreMetadata="no" notifyOnBackupComplete="no" selectable="yes" selectableForRestore="no" componentFlags="0"><FILE_LIST path="%SystemRoot%\Repair\Backup\BootableSystemState\Registry" filespec="default" filespecBackupType="3855"/><FILE_LIST path="%SystemRoot%\Repair\Backup\BootableSystemState\Registry" filespec="SAM" filespecBackupType="3855"/><FILE_LIST path="%SystemRoot%\Repair\Backup\BootableSystemState\Registry" filespec="SECURITY" filespecBackupType="3855"/><FILE_LIST path="%SystemRoot%\Repair\Backup\BootableSystemState\Registry" filespec="software" filespecBackupType="3855"/><FILE_LIST path="%SystemRoot%\Repair\Backup\BootableSystemState\Registry" filespec="system" filespecBackupType="3855"/></FILE_GROUP><EXCLUDE_FILES path="%SystemRoot%\system32\config" filespec="default" recursive="no"/><EXCLUDE_FILES path="%SystemRoot%\system32\config" filespec="default.LOG" recursive="no"/><EXCLUDE_FILES path="%SystemRoot%\system32\config" filespec="default.sav" recursive="no"/><EXCLUDE_FILES path="%SystemRoot%\system32\config" filespec="SAM" recursive="no"/><EXCLUDE_FILES path="%SystemRoot%\system32\config" filespec="SAM.LOG" recursive="no"/><EXCLUDE_FILES path="%SystemRoot%\system32\config" filespec="SECURITY" recursive="no"/><EXCLUDE_FILES path="%SystemRoot%\system32\config" filespec="SECURITY.LOG" recursive="no"/><EXCLUDE_FILES path="%SystemRoot%\system32\config" filespec="software" recursive="no"/><EXCLUDE_FILES path="%SystemRoot%\system32\config" filespec="software.LOG" recursive="no"/><EXCLUDE_FILES path="%SystemRoot%\system32\config" filespec="software.sav" recursive="no"/><EXCLUDE_FILES path="%SystemRoot%\system32\config" filespec="system" recursive="no"/><EXCLUDE_FILES path="%SystemRoot%\system32\config" filespec="system.LOG" recursive="no"/><EXCLUDE_FILES path="%SystemRoot%\system32\config" filespec="system.sav" recursive="no"/></BACKUP_LOCATIONS></WRITER_METADATA>].
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868  ERR                                         COM error: Error opening input file: 'x-schema:#VssWriterMetadataInfo'.
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868  ERR                                         The system cannot locate the resource specified.
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868  ERR                                          Code: 0x1
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868                                      Creating an offline version of writers metadata.. Ok.
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868                              Serializing VSS writers metadata. Ok.
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868                              Serializing BackupComponents document
12/02/2016 10:20:13   5868                              Serializing BackupComponents document. Failed.
```

The problem started on the 9th Feb which was the same day that the VMWare ESX Hosts where patched and memory upgraded and therefore the VM was migrated to another host but was moved back to it's original host.  VMWare tools was only upgraded after finding out that the backup was failing.

All other Veeam backups of similar Windows 2003 R2 SP2 Servers on the same ESX Host work fine but I'm at a loss as to why this one fails, any assistance with this appreciated!

Comment: Is the ESXi Host or the vCenter Server added to the Veeam Backup Infrastructure?

Comment: Yes, the VC is backed up by Veeam in the same job.

Comment: We've also created a new job just for this server and the same error is returned.

Comment: Server 2003 is EoL.  Upgrade.

Comment: Thanks, that's the plan but doesn't help me with backing up this particular server right now.

Answer (score 1):

This was caused by having the Application Aware Processing enabled for this particular VM and therefore not allowing a successful Quiesced snapshot. Disabling this feature allows the VM to backup successfully.

Comment: I don't use guest quiescing at all - it was pretty troublesome when we bought Veeam years ago and I've never needed it. It's much better to run separate SQL or AD backup jobs and if everything fails you've got the files.